# Vertical space between horizontal lines

Tags: spacing, rules

I have defined a macro for 2 closely spaced horizontal lines,

```
\newcommand{\myline}{\par\noindent% 
\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt} \\[-0.80\baselineskip]%
\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}
```

Now I noticed that when putting it at different places in the text and at different environments, results in a slightly different vertical spacing between them. Is it possible to fix the spacing between them? (regardless of the line spacing in the environment they are inside)

**Edit:**

also when defining a linespace in definite units, it still depends on the font. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myline}{\par\noindent% 
\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt} \\[-9pt]%
\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent \blindtext
    \myline

\begin{quotation}
    \small \myline
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just write `\\[-3pt]` or something like this with an explicit length (`\baselineskip` can change across environments). An example would be useful, anyway.

Comment: @egreg See my edit

Comment: `\\[x]` doesn't work, it starts a new line after `x`. Even if `x` is explicit, the newline is not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try

```
\newcommand{\myline}{\par
  \kern3pt % space above the rules
  \hrule height 1.5pt
  \kern2pt % space between the rules
  \hrule height 0.8pt
  \kern3pt % space below the rules
}
```

Change the spacings to suit your needs.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you are using `\baselineskip`, rather use a fixed value `\\[3pt]`